# Use XML HTTP Request On Sites That Require Object Interaction

Tags: json, xml, vba, http, web-scraping

I am working on a project to scrape information from a number of websites. I have a number of sites working with no issue, largely processing them by amending the URL to pass through the relevant criteria or by posting `AJAX` requests. I am fairly new to this so I am seeking some assistance.

I have come across a website where I need to interact with objects on a page in order to obtain further information. An example of this is the below site:

[Example Site](http://www.blackcircles.com/order/tyres/search?width=205&profile=55&rim=R16&speed=V&vehicle-make=&postcode=&delivery=1&findTyre=)

If you visit the site and go to the bottom there are more brands and clicking "view" will display additional products. The `HTML` for these is only returned once clicked.

With other sites I have sourced information from I have used the below approach. **Is there a way to process the page via the XML HTTP Method after a page object action has been performed?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. At the moment I am assuming I will have to stick to scraping such sites using an Internet Explorer object.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub sbKF()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsIn As ADODB.Recordset
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument

Dim strUrl As String
Dim strPost As String

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

Set rsIn = New ADODB.Recordset

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

rsIn.Open pcstrInput, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

rsIn.MoveLast: rsIn.MoveFirst

Do While Not rsIn.EOF

    ' Create the URL and Post submission for input size.
    strUrl = "http://www.[Site].com"
    strPost = "Stage=2&sop=TyreSize&ssq=1&vnp=&vmk=&vch=&vmo=&drd="

    ' Return the Document body results
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = fnPostXmlHttp(strUrl, strPost)

    rsIn.MoveNext

Loop
End Sub

Public Function fnPostXmlHttp(ByVal strUrl As String, ByVal strScript As String)

Dim XMLHttpRequest As Object
Dim strOut As String

Set XMLHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

XMLHttpRequest.Open "POST", strUrl, False
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
XMLHttpRequest.send (strScript)

While XMLHttpRequest.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

fnPostXmlHttp = XMLHttpRequest.responseText
End Function
```

Comment: Website API availability makes web-scraping much more straightforward. If you get data from a website via XHR, then you will have to examine XHRs and how the website works via developer tools to find out all necessary headers, query params, form data and sent them with XHR. I've tried to do that with your example site: the response for  the additional products at the bottom is a json string, but I can't reproduce the browser's XHR in VBA since the origin of some headers isn't clear.

Comment: I agree with omegastripes. You have to manually parse pages. You might try iMacros. http://imacros.net/overview It might save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at www.blackcircles.com HTML response, you will see the javascript snippet:

```js
...
var newTyresActionUrl;
var lookupAddress;

$(document).ready(function () {

    newTyresActionUrl = new BC.classes.productV6SearchPage('https://www.blackcircles.com/order/tyres',
        {"Error":false,"VariantFitments":[{"Name":"All Season","VariantType":11,"SeasonalType":true,"TruckType":false,"FriendlyName":"allseason","Count":17,
        ...
        "TakeoverCss":"\u003clink id=\"brandtakeover-css\" rel=\u0027stylesheet\u0027 type=\u0027text/css\u0027 href=\u0027/templates/bcstyles/css/goodyear-effgrip-perf.css\u0027\u003e"},
        "Width", 
        "Profile",
        "Rim",
        "Speed",
        "Method",
        true,
        ""
    );

    addToBasket = new BC.classes.addtobasket('https://www.blackcircles.com/order/tyres', "order", '/truck/garages');
    ...
```

Actually the portion within curly braces represents a JSON object containing all displayed on the webpage data. So you can extract that JSON string from HTML content by `Instr()`, parse it, convert to arrays and output to the worksheet, as shown in the example code below. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_blackcircles()

    Dim sResp As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vItem
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.blackcircles.com/order/tyres/search?width=205&profile=55&rim=R16&speed=V&vehicle-make=&postcode=&delivery=1&findTyre=", False
        .send
        sResp = .responseText
    End With
    sResp = getFragment(sResp, "new BC.classes.productV6SearchPage", "new BC.classes.addtobasket")
    sResp = getFragment(sResp, "{", "}")
    sResp = "{" & sResp & "}"
    JSON.Parse sResp, vJSON, sState
    i = 1
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        For Each vItem In Array( _
                "Manufacturers", _
                "CarManufacturers", _
                "All", _
                "Deals", _
                "Best", _
                "Rest", _
                "SearchParams" _
                )
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = vItem
            JSON.ToArray vJSON(vItem), aData, aHeader
            OutputArray .Cells(i + 2, 1), aHeader
            Output2DArray .Cells(i + 3, 1), aData
            .Columns.AutoFit
            i = i + UBound(aData, 1) + 5

        Next
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function getFragment( _
    sourceText As String, _
    startPattern As String, _
    endPattern As String _
) As String

    Dim startPos
    startPos = InStr(sourceText, startPattern)
    If startPos = 0 Then Exit Function
    Dim partText
    partText = Mid(sourceText, startPos + Len(startPattern))
    Dim endPos
    endPos = InStrRev(partText, endPattern)
    If endPos = 0 Then Exit Function
    getFragment = Left(partText, endPos - 1)

End Function
```

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: I get variable not defined for JSON in the above. JSON.Parse sResp, vJSON, sStat. I have downloaded the bas but as it is not showing as a class how am I getting a method called .Parse and having an object called JSON please?

Comment: You should import the downloaded file `JSON.bas` into the VBA project, but not copy-paste the code. Thus you will have `JSON` module in the project, and will be able to call public subs and fns from it using standard notation e. g. `JSON.Parse`.

Comment: Thank you. I apologise for my "too early morning" head.